# NSXMLParser stops parsing when it finds comments in the XML file

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I'm parsing XML using an `NSXMLParser`, but when finds comments like this:

```
<!-- ------------------------------------------- -->
<!--           This is a comment             -->
```

The parser stops parsing. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Did it call the error delegate method that you're implementing to log error conditions?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [NSXMLParser docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

> An `NSXMLParser` notifies its delegate about the items (elements, attributes, CDATA blocks, **comments**, and so on) that it encounters as it processes an XML document. It does not itself do anything with those parsed items except report them. It also reports parsing errors.

Therefore, you probably need to implement the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLParser/delegate) (protocol reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate)) to catch these notifications:

[`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundComment:(NSString *)comment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser%3afoundComment%3a)